# With WordPress and Make, why are two different interfaces coming up for editing posts?

Tags: wordpress

I am designing a blog with Wordpress, using the Make theme with a few alterations I have made to its style.css file<sup>*</sup>.

My site is not yet online and I have written three example posts only. The following problem has arisen: when I log into wp-admin and start to edit the third post, or when I add a new post (Posts | Add New), I get a different interface from the one I get when I edit either of the first two posts.

Screenshot from "All posts":

[image]

As you can see, all three posts are listed. But when I start editing the second, I get this

[image]

and when I start editing the third, I get this:

[image]

They both seem to be using the Make theme, but they are different. How come? I have done the same thing in both cases: I have hovered over the name of the post ("Second post" or "Third article") and I have then clicked on "Edit". So why doesn't the same thing happen both times? I would like to get the same interface - the one that comes up for the first two posts - when I write or edit any post.

Edit: I think I may be getting the Gutenberg editor for the first two posts and some other editor for the third post and any new posts. I didn't find this explicitly stated anywhere, but the sentence "Access all block and document tools in a single place" seems to be Gutenberg-specific. If someone is reading this who is familiar with Gutenberg, they will probaly be able to confirm from the screenshot. If this is accurate then the question boils down to how can I get the Gutenberg editor for all posts. I have no idea why I am getting two different editors.

<sup>* Minor things that stop posts from displaying categories, set a maximum width, and set the colour of the dropped cap</sup>

Comment: I may be making some progress towards working this out. The "Block Editor" *is* the Gutenberg editor - they are the same thing, right? So this looks like a bug either in Gutenberg or in the Classic editor, but given the problems that some users are reporting in respect of Gutenberg, the problem probably lies there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises because the site builder that is part of the Make theme requires the Classic editor to work, except for some posts for which it is able to use the Gutenberg (also known as the "block") editor.

Solutions therefore include finding a way to drop caps using the Classic editor while continuing to use the Make theme, and using a theme other than Make while continuing to use the Gutenberg editor. Just do not try to use both Make and Gutenberg at the same time because this does not seem to work for all posts in the desired collection.